# Find the \$\left(n^2\right)^\text{th }n\$-gonal number

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer

Given a non-negative integer, \$n\$, yield the \$(n^2)^\text{th } n\$-gonal number.

#### Further Detail:

The \$x\$-gonal numbers, or *polygonal numbers*, are also known as the *two-dimensional figurate numbers*.

Many people will be familiar with the triangular numbers, these are the \$3\$-gonal numbers:

$$F(3,n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

The triangular numbers are [OEIS A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217):

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190, ...
```

Probably even more will be familiar with the square numbers, these are the \$4\$-gonal numbers:

$$F(4,n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)=n^{2}$$

The square numbers are [OEIS A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290):

```
0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, ...
```

In general the \$k^\text{th }x\$-gonal number is the number of pebbles required to iteratively build up an \$x\$-sided polygon by adding pebbles to \$x-2\$ of the sides, here are a few formulae:

\begin{align}
F(x,k)&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(1+\sum_{j=2}^{i}(x-2)\right) \\
&=\frac{k^2(x-2)-k(x-4)}{2} \\ 
&=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}(x-2)+k\\
&=(x-3)\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(i)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}(i)\\
&=(x-2)(k-1)+1+F(x,k-1)
\end{align}

I'm sure there are plenty more.
Note that the last one is recursive but that \$F(x,0)=0\$.

#### The challenge

...is to golf code for \$G(n)=F(n,n^2)\$ for non-negative \$n\$.
i.e. Given a non-negative integer, \$n\$, yield the \$(n^2)^\text{th } n\$-gonal number.
This is not (currently) in the OEIS:

```
0, 1, 4, 45, 256, 925, 2556, 5929, 12160, 22761, 39700, 65461, 103104, 156325, 229516, 327825, 457216, 624529, 837540, 1105021, ...
```

#### Notes

You may yield a list of these numbers up to and including the required one if preferred.
For example, given an input of `5` you may yield either:

- the integer `925`, or
- the list `[0, 1, 4, 45, 256, 925]`
- ...**but not `[0, 1, 4, 45, 256]` or `[1, 4, 45, 256, 925]`**

Results may also be results of floating point calculation and may deviate as such, so long as infinite precision floating point arithmetic would yield correct results.

---

Win by creating the shortest code in bytes in a language. The overall winner will be the shortest across all languages, but please don't let golfing languages dissuade you from entering in your favourite language - the primary goals are to challenge yourself and have fun!

Comment: `Results may also be results of floating point calculation and may deviate as such` -- are possible integer overflows also acceptable?

Comment: @JonathanFrech indeed, that would certainly be a default (the floating point stuff probably is too, but thought it best to say since it's an integer based challenge)

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
#(4-#-2#^2+#^3)#/2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8V9Zw0RXWddIOc5IWznOWFNZ30jtv6Y1V0BRZl5JtLKCrp1CmoNyrJq@Q1BiXnpqtIGOoUHsfwA)

Just a golfy version of the second formula.

### With [`PolygonalNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolygonalNumber.html) built-in, 23 bytes

```
PolygonalNumber[#,#^2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8T8gP6cyPT8vMcevNDcptShaWUc5zihW7b@mNVdAUWZeSbSygq6dQpqDcqyavkNQYl56arSBjqFB7H8A)

As expected, the Mathematica built-in is longer than the golfed version.

Answer (score 5):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

```
ᛦℙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@HsZY9aZv7/bwoA)

¯\_(ツ)_/¯ First Neim answer, right tool for the job. By the way, the advice I give on my *About me* page still holds for my own posts: [Don't upvote trivial solutions, please](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-we-help-users-who-are-put-off-by-the-use-of-golfing-languages/10132#10132).

Comment: Finding the right language is a +1 from me :p

Comment: Upvoted because when I saw the question I immediately thought "oh, Neim can do this in 2 bytes". But someone beat me to it!

Comment: Upvoted because I am oppositional by nature.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
²Ḷ×_2$‘S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Qpoc7th2eHm@k8qhhRvD///8tAQ)

In short, it generates the range \$[0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)^2]\$, multiplies every integer in that range with \$n-2\$, increments each of them (to avoid adding \$n^2\$ at the end, saving 1 byte), then sums the resulting list.

Comment: Ah ha you found the 1-byte save I knew must have been there (had `_2×²Ṗ$S+²` , `²ṖS×’’$+²` and many other 9 variants)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thank you for the edits.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
nsÅU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9ocHhuWaW9koKunYKSfWXl/7ziw62h/21r/wMA)

Comment: I thought you'd been really clever for a second there.

Comment: @JonathanAllan ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯... Right tool for the job. Actually, give me a second to try Neim :P

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> 9 bytes

```
smh*d-Q2*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzg3QytFN9BI6/9/UwA)

Comment: `shM*R-Q2*` saves 5 whole bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder yeah, found a similar 9 byte solution right before you posted that...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```python
lambda k:(k*k*(k-2)-k+4)*k*k/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSiNbK1tLI1vXSFM3W9tEE8jJ1gcqyS9SyFTIzFMoSsxLT9UwNNC04lIoKMrMK1HI1EnTyNT8DwA)

---

Saved:

- -1 byte, thanks to joH1

Comment: 30 bytes: [`lambda k:(k*k*(k-2)-k+4)*k*k/2`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSiNbK1tLI1vXSFM3W9tEE8jJ1gcqyS9SyFTIzFMoSsxLT9UwNNC04lIoKMrMK1HI1EnTyNT8DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 26 bytes

```javascript
n=>n**4*(n-2)-n*n*(n-4)>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5PS8tESyNP10hTN08rD8Qy0bSzM/yfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RpmGpqfkfAA)

---

## Recursive (ES6), 33 bytes

A quick attempt from mobile. Not really optimized for \$(n,n^2)\$.

```javascript
x=>(g=k=>k&&(x-2)*--k-~g(k))(x*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADA35CWpA5uDuUvBIFoCTViTCe/jndnfONI93E91HXPs/A0DlBZOIhzYLSiJxL6KggimDecSfvQlpemFQpsiPMH)

Comment: Golfing from mobile and still FGITW :o (helps having no weird code-page I guess)

Comment: It definitely helps. :) (Or I'd need another phone, I guess...)

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), 20 bytes

```
$0:$$+$$/2($$-1)($-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8XASkVFW0VF30hDRUXXUFNDRdfo/38A)

### Explanation

```
$0                      Zero indexing
  :                     Mode: sequence (output nth term)
                        Each term equals:
   $$+                    index * index +
      $$/2                index * index / 2 * 
          ($$-1)($-2      (index * index - 1) * (index - 2
                    )    ) implicit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
Ｉ⊘↨⟦¹±²±¹¦⁴¦⁰¦⁰⟧Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyMxpyw1RcMpsThVI9pQR8EvNT2xJFXDSBPONAQyTXQUDIAoVkfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDEwSs//83/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the second formula expanded into the polynomial \$ \frac{1}{2} ( x^5 - 2x^4 - x^3 + 4x^2 ) \$ which is calculated by treating it as an arbitrary base conversion before halving and casting to string for implicit output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Physica](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Physica), 25 bytes

```
->n:(n^4-n^2)/2*(n-2)+n^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvzvZhvzX9cuz0ojL85ENy/OSFPfSEsjT9dIUxvI@R9QlJlXEu0W7ZlXUFqiEhv73xIA)

---

```
->n:n^2*(4-n-2*n^2+n^3)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvzvZhvzX9cuzyovzkhLw0Q3T9dIC8jUzosz1tQ3@h9QlJlXEu0W7ZlXUFqiEhv73xIA)

---

```
->n:n^5/2-n^4-n^3/2+2*n*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvzvZhvzX9cuzyovzlTfSDcvzgSIjfWNtI208rTy/gcUZeaVRLtFe@YVlJaoxMb@twQA) | **[Try all of them at once as a test suite!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvz/31HBVkHXLs9KIy/ORDcvzkhT30hLI0/XSFMbyOFygsoC2VoaQHldIy0gEyhlDFTH5QyXNdU30oUYYKxvpA1UpJXHxeWWX6TgqfCoo0Mh2kDhUcMyBUODWCsuzoCizLyS6OCSomjPWL2crNLikmjjWGsFJaBRStYKIHFHB7iMoWksRMwJi5gziljs//8A)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
²µ½_2×’H×+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//wrLCtcK9XzLDl@KAmUjDlyv/UjA7w4figqw7IkAkR///MTA)

Uses the formula \$F(x,k)=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}(x-2)+k\$ as given in the challenge.

Comment: I have less but don't think I have optimal yet.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 38 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$x=x^2*(x^3/2-x^2-x/2+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLpcK2Is5IS6MizljfSBfI1K3QN9I20vwfXJIIVGWroKJg@v9fclpOYnrxf11Pn/8ulXmJuZnJxQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
×⍨×2+×⍨-⍨.5×*∘3-⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0x/1rjg83UgbzNAFYj3Tw9O1HnXMMNZ91LUIqEjh0IpHvZsNDQA)

Comment: You may want to include `0` in your test-suite

Comment: `2+×⍨-⍨` → `2-×⍨-`

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
U:qG2-*Qs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9Sq0N1IVyuw@P9/cwA)

This uses [Mr. Xcoder's Jelly approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171257/36398).

Comment: FYI the approach is just a small step from the 4th formula (with the two sums), or, indeed, the 3rd (replace the triangle-number-esque formula with a sum) :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes, I had noticed about the third, but not about the fourth. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 23 bytes

```
{((x-2)*k%2%k-1)+k:x*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWkOjQtdIUytb1Ug1W9dQUzvbqkKrovZ/mrqikcF/AA)

Prefix function; implementation of the second formula: \$\frac{k(k-1)}{2}(x-2)+k\$

#### How:

```
{((x-2)*k%2%k-1)+k:x*x} # Main function, argument x.
                 k:x*x  # def k = n²
 ((x-2)*k%2%k-1)+       # calculate k + (((k/2)/(k-1))*(x-2))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (31 bytes)

```
g k=(k*k*k*k*(k-2)-k*k*(k-4))/2
```

Comment: `k**4` instead of `k*k*k*k`.

Comment: or `k^4`. But the equation may be rearranged a little: `(k^4*(k-2)-k*k*(k-4))/2 = ((k*k*(k-2)-k+4)*k*k)/2 = ((k^3-2*k-k+4)*k*k)/2` - so this gives the 25 byte version: `g k=(k^3-2*k*k-k+4)*k*k/2` Here is an online IDE link - [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P10h21YjO85Y10grWytbN1vbRBPE0Df6n5uYmWdbUJSZV6ISna5QoVADxDa6CtEGenqGlrGx/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
f k=(k^4*(k-2)-k^2*(k-4))/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h21YjO85ESyNb10hTNzvOCMQy0dTUN/qfm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioKKQpmBo8B8A)

My first attempt at golfing in Haskell, basically same as almost any answer :

Nothing worth explaining here.

Comment: Nice. I gave a golfed version to Davide Spataro, since they posted earlier, (my first attempt at golfing Haskell too :))

Comment: @JonathanAllan you did better than me, (your formula was better). Seeing there is already an existing Haskell answer, do you want me to delete mine ?

Comment: Some people delete if they find the same (or effectively the same) solution, but I think if one finds it independently there is nothing wrong with keeping it.

Comment: @JonathanAllan then for now, I'll let it stay :)\

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <del>60</del> <del>36</del> 34 bytes

-24 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171235/find-the-leftn2-right-textth-n-gonal-number#comment413854_171460)

-2 bytes by factorizing again an `n*n` expression.

```c
g(n){return(n*n*(n-2)-n+4)*n*n/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/LCoMwEIXhdX2KIaWQ2NqLN6iWPokbm6QxEEfRpBTEZ7cB6d7l8A8fHB4pzpe9Rm6ckPAYrdDduXkuiiKbBmndgBRDDClGMYvwmDJ/4CUu50WjhbbWSD@dFgymYNc7O1Jytw0kkeqwNoCufcmBsHKNAJTIby@5lQKggDRb0@CtNyW8NtyZ2scCDqLCCskJFE2Yf/rrt9zz6TY@zvItfrr661q4lsG8/AA)

Factored version of the second formula, uses a single function.

Entry point is function `g(n)`, value is returned as integer.

Comment: `g(n){return(n*n*n-2*n*n-n+4)*n*n/2;}` is 36 bytes (is it golfable?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks! I factorized as much as I could, I don't think it can't be golfed down again, at least not using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->n{(4-n+(n-2)*n*=n)*n/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNEN09bI0/XSFMrT8s2D0jqG9X@1zDQ0zM00NTLTSyorqmoKVBIi66Irf0PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 4 bytes

```
Đ²⇹ᑭ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRDmx6173w4ce3//9GGOkY6xjomOqaxAA)

#### Explanation:

```
        Implicit input
Đ       Duplicate
 ²      Square
  ⇹     Swap top two elements on the stack
   ᑭ    Get the (n^2)th n-gonal number
        Implicit output
```